# Read more Read less text Issue with truncate and substring in Smarty3

Tags: javascript, php, smarty3

## Heading

I am trying to implement the Read more and Read less option in the smarty template using javascript but I have the below issue with output text where some of the characters are missing when I click on the read more button. Seems like an issue with Truncate and the `substr` function and it is not constant for each row in the table.

The max size of $Test->description is 200 characters and it has different text length, some 120, 150, 200..etc.

I am trying to display the first 100 characters using truncate function

```
{$Test->description|truncate:100:""}
```

and then after clicking read more button the remaining characters from 101 to 200 using substr function

```
{$Test->description|substr:101:200}
```

.

This logic seems to be working for only a few rows, not on all the rows.

Can someone please suggest a fix for this?

test.tpl file:

```
    {foreach ... }
                                
        
        
    {$Test->description|truncate:100:""}{$Test->description|substr:101:200}Read more
                                    
                                        {literal}
                                        #more{/literal}{$smarty.foreach.count.index}{literal} {display: none;}
                                        .button{/literal}{$smarty.foreach.count.index}{literal} {
                                            background-color: white;
                                            color: black;
                                            border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
                                            width:auto;
                                            font-size: 10px;
                                        }
    
                                        .button{/literal}{$smarty.foreach.count.index}{literal}:hover {
                                            background-color: #e7e7e7;
                                            width:auto;
                                            font-size: 10px;
                                        }
    
                                        {/literal}
                                    
                                <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
                                    {literal}
                                    function myFunction{/literal}{$smarty.foreach.count.index}{literal}() {
                                        var dots = document.getElementById("dots{/literal}{$smarty.foreach.count.index}{literal}");
                                        var moreText = document.getElementById("more{/literal}{$smarty.foreach.count.index}{literal}");
                                        var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn{/literal}{$smarty.foreach.count.index}{literal}");

                                        if (dots.style.display === "none") {
                                            dots.style.display = "inline";
                                            btnText.innerHTML = "Read more";
                                            moreText.style.display = "none";
                                        } else {
                                            dots.style.display = "none";
                                            btnText.innerHTML = "Read less";
                                            moreText.style.display = "inline";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    {/literal}
                                </script>
                                </td>
                        </tr>

                {/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer

{$Test->description|truncate:100:"":TRUE}
{$Test->description|substr:100:200}